# Graphical model - log transformed covariance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stochastic-calculus, covariance

It is known that the non-zero entries of the inverse covariance matrix constitute an estimate on the edges in a graphical model. I wonder if there is an analog or similar result for the log-transformed of the covariance matrix (which applies the logarithm on all eigenvalues). I'm happy for any inputs.

Comment: Sorry but what is the probability interpretation of the log covariance matrix? The inverse of covariance matrix, which is precision matrix could signal conditional correlation, AFAIK

Comment: I guess/hope it is similar to the Fisher transformation of the off-diagonal elements. So I thought maybe there is an analog interpretation like there is a zero in Log-transform if and only if there is a zero in the precision matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a super interesting question! I don't have an answer to it and interested to know if someone know literature along this line.

---

Here are some numerical experiments to show that a sparse precision matrix do not usually correspond to a sparse log-transformed precision or covariance matrix. or inverse of log covariance.

Given a chain-like model, its precision matrix shall be band-like sparse.
$$
C^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix}
2   &  1  &   0   &  0\\
     1  &   2  &   1  &  0\\
     0   &  1   &  2  &   1\\
     0   &  0   &  1  &   2\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Its covariance matrix is not sparse
$$
C^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix}
    0.8000 &  -0.6000 &   0.4000 &  -0.2000\\
   -0.6000 &   1.2000 &  -0.8000 &   0.4000\\
    0.4000 &  -0.8000 &   1.2000 &  -0.6000\\
   -0.2000 &   0.4000 &  -0.6000 &   0.8000\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Similarly the log transformed $C$ or $C^{-1}$ are also not sparse... same for $(\log C)^{-1}$, they are all dense matrices, I cannot read the chain graph structure from these matrices...
$$
-\log C =\log C^{-1}= \begin{bmatrix}
   -0.5100 &  -0.6456 &   0.2152 &  -0.0796\\
   -0.6456 &  -0.2948 &  -0.7252 &   0.2152\\
    0.2152 &  -0.7252 &  -0.2948 &  -0.6456\\
   -0.0796 &   0.2152 &  -0.6456 &  -0.5100\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
(\log C)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1.4582 &  -0.0526 &  -0.9820 &   0.9935\\
   -0.0526 &   0.4762 &   0.9409 &  -0.9820\\
   -0.9820 &   0.9409 &   0.4762 &  -0.0526\\
    0.9935 &  -0.9820 &  -0.0526 &   1.4582\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$